# Find all transitive artifacts with used classes

Tags: maven, neo4j, jqassistant

I am using jqassistant to create a transitive dependency list of artifacts. My aim is to base this on the type dependencies because I want to find architecture deficits by comparing the Maven transitive dependency list with the one given by type dependencies (all artifacts of which at least one type is used in any transitive form).

Unfortunately, the following query only gave back the original artifact `basis-vs-bo`. The query was applied to a database that I created by scanning a Maven repository.

What did I miss?

```
 MATCH (basis:Artifact{name:"basis-vs-bo",version:"4.0.0"})
 WHERE NOT( HAS (basis.classifier))
 WITH basis
 MATCH (basis) -[:CONTAINS]-> (t:Type) -[:DEPENDS_ON*]-> (s:Type) <-[:CONTAINS]- (a:Artifact)
 RETURN DISTINCT a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maven repository scanner treats all artifacts in isolation, i.e. dependencies between them are not evaluated while scanning classes.

This is the same behavior as scanning several JAR files from a directory, so dependencies between classes (method invocations, inheritance hierarchies, etc.) are only resolved if the involved classes are located within the same artifact.

As the dependencies between the artifacts are known in the case of the Maven repository it should be possible to apply queries which resolve these dependencies similar to the "classpath:*" concepts but this needs to be evaluated.

**Update**

The following queries should help getting class based dependencies (DEPENDS_ON) between classes in different artifacts:

Build DEPENDS_ON relations between artifacts based on declared dependencies in POMs:

```
MATCH
  (r:Repository)-[:CONTAINS_POM]->(p1:Pom)-[:DESCRIBES]->(a1:Java:Archive),
  (r:Repository)-[:CONTAINS_POM]->(p2:Pom)-[:DESCRIBES]->(a2:Java:Archive),
  (p1)-[:DECLARES_DEPENDENCY]->(a2)
MERGE
  (a1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(a2)
RETURN
  a1.fqn, collect(a2.fqn)
```

Resolve types required by an artifact to those contained in an artifact which is a dependency, a relation RESOLVES_TO is created:

```
MATCH
  (a1:Artifact)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(a2:Artifact),
  (a1)-[:REQUIRES]->(requiredType:Type),
  (a2)-[:CONTAINS]->(containedType:Type)
WHERE
  requiredType.fqn = containedType.fqn
MERGE
  (requiredType)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->(containedType)
RETURN
  a1.fqn, a2.fqn, collect(requiredType.fqn)
```

Propagate DEPENDS_ON relations between types based on the RESOLVES_TO relation:

```
MATCH
  (a1:Artifact)-[:REQUIRES]->(requiredType:Type),
  (a1)-[:CONTAINS]->(type:Type)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(requiredType),
  (a2:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(resolvedType:Type),
  (requiredType)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->(resolvedType:Type)
MERGE
  (type)-[dependsOn:DEPENDS_ON]->(resolvedType)
SET
  dependsOn.resolved=true
RETURN
  a1.fqn, type.fqn, a2.fqn, collect(resolvedType.fqn)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it would be great to use the structure of the Maven repo (esp. the POMs) to avoid "duplicated nodes". Then it would be much easier to find architectural problems in our large company Maven repo.

Comment: Thank you for your fast update. I am currently waiting for the second query (takes some time in a 144GB database...). I'm on holiday next week and then I'll come to Dresden for your seminar, so don't expect me to answer too soon.